# Add user input to start of list using UseEffect with Redux and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

First things first, my code is working and pulling data from Redux like it should. All input boxes receives user input and submits it perfectly after submit (as seen in my console).

The only problem I'm having is figuring out how to send that information to the actual DOM in my useEffect(). Preferably I'd like it to display at the top of the current list (unshift()) instead of the bottom when new data is submitted by user.

I have been staring at this for so long that I'm pretty sure I'm probably over thinking it. Any help though would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions';

const Posts = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(setData(props.fetchPosts())){
            props.posts.unshift(...props.post, props.newPost);
        }

    },[props.newPost]) 

    console.log('new post',props.newPost)
    const postItems = props.posts.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <p>{item.body}</p> 
        </div>
    ))

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            {postItems}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.posts.items, 
    newPost: state.posts.item 
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

Comment: You don't want to mutate props, that's going to bring you issues, what you'd rather do is to execute a callback sent from the parent component or notify the parent component to do it there.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to solve this issue.

```
1. Update state value (props are immutable).

 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions';

 const Posts = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);


   useEffect(() => {
    if(props.fetchPosts()){
      let dupData = [...data]
      dupData.unShift(props.newPost)
      setData(dupData)
    }

 },[props.newPost]) 

 console.log('new post',props.newPost)
 let updatedPosts = [data, ...props.posts]
 const postItems = updatedPosts.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <p>{item.body}</p> 
    </div>
 ))

 return (
    <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        {postItems}
    </div>
  )
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   posts: state.posts.items, 
   newPost: state.posts.item 
 })
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

2. Update redux state

Answer (score 0):

If you simply render the postItems based on your Redux state, I think the issue should be solved. Dispatching an action in useEffect will change the Redux state which should automatically trigger a rerender of the component. You can also consider dispatching an action directly upon the submission of the form, this may make everything a bit cleaner.

Also, I would not recommend using the useState hook here as it is not necessary here if you're also using Redux (in this component). A good practice is to use the useState hook only for state that is local to the component and is not helpful to any others in your app.